# Holding Vector of unique value set for color selection using C++ and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, colors, selection

I'm part of a project where I am handling the selection method for a 3D rendering of a pipe system. to be able to select the pipes, my research suggests that color picking would be the best method (due to the number of pipes, ray selection may be more difficult).

```
//define color for pipe
int lowc=0;
int highc=9;
float cB = (rand()%(highc-lowc+1)+lowc)/10.0;
float cG = (rand()%(highc-lowc+1)+lowc)/10.0;
float cR = (rand()%(highc-lowc+1)+lowc)/10.0;
//some way of confirming the complete color combination is unique.

 // Create and insert new pipe in a new branch..
 Pipe* new_p = new Pipe(new_n1, new_n2, d, wf,cB,cG,cR);
 ElementList* new_branch = new ElementList();
 new_branch->branch->Append(new_n1);
 new_branch->branch->Append(new_p);
 new_branch->branch->Append(new_n2);
```

At the moment I'm struggling to figure out the most efficient way to check whether the defined color already exists. Storing a vector of all 1000 current color combinations seems too time consuming, as does referencing all other existing nodes color values for each. Would there be any better solution for storing a vector of existing colors (eg <0.2, 0.6, 0.4>, <0.8, 0.1, 0.1>, etc) and comparing it with any other existing vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example for picking triangles of an object. You should change this example into rendering tube indices instead of face indices.

```
PickingModeBegin(); // see below

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (FaceIndex fi = 0; fi < GetFacesSize(); fi++) {
    const Face & face = faces[fi];
    glColor3ub((fi >> 16) & 255, (fi >> 8) & 255, (fi & 255)); // color coded index
    glVertex3fv(vertices[face.a].GetPointer());
    glVertex3fv(vertices[face.b].GetPointer());
    glVertex3fv(vertices[face.c].GetPointer());
}
glEnd();

PickingModeEnd(); // see below

glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);                          
GLint viewportInfo[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewportInfo);             

GLubyte pixel[3];
// read the color
glReadPixels(mousePosX, viewportInfo[3] - mousePosY, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);             

// extract face index
int selectedFaceIdx = (pixel[0] << 16) + (pixel[1] << 8) + pixel[2]; 



void PickingModeBegin(void) {
  glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glCullFace(GL_BACK);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);


  // turn off everything
  glDisable(GL_BLEND);
  glDisable(GL_DITHER);
  glDisable(GL_FOG);
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

  glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

}

void PickingModeEnd(void) {
  glPopAttrib();
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to be more focused on finding the color already assigned to a face, where as I am still aiming to generate this face/pipe color in the first place. Unless I'm misreading it somewhere.

Comment: The concept here is to render indices of some objects (faces, tubes resp.). This rendering is never displayed but only read at the mouse position. You can give an identification number to each object (= tube in your case) and color-code that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ColourValue
{
    int red, blue, green;

    ColourValue() : red(0), blue(0), green(0) {}
    ColourValue(int red, int blue, int green) : red(red), blue(blue), green(green) {}

    bool operator < (const ColourValue& other) const
    {
        // magic trick to sort in set
        return pair<int, pair<int, int>>(this->red, pair<int, int>(this->blue, this->green))
        < pair<int, pair<int, int>>(other.red, pair<int, int>(other.blue, other.green));
    }
};

set<ColourValue> all_colours;
```